# recommended way to convert Double -> Float in Haskell

Tags: haskell, floating-point, coercion

What is the idiomatic way to go `Double -> Float`?

Is it `uncurry encodeFloat . decodeFloat` ?

(I am using [`gloss`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss), this requires Floats)

And what is the recommended way to find an answer to such questions?

I was trying [this hoogle query](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Double+-%3E+Float) but the answers are all very unhelpful
(try it - it has `unsafeCoerce` at the top of the list)

Comment: That is going to be a painful conversion.

Comment: @Jefffrey: are you saying that any such conversion would be painful, or that particular implementation is?

Comment: I'm not sure, because I remember `Float` being "special" in Haskell, and I remember being told to avoid it like the plague, but in general "double" means double precision floating point number, and it's generally 64 bits, while "float" is a single precision floating point number, which is generally 32 bits. You can clearly see that it's a loss conversion if that's the case.

Comment: @Jefffrey : loss does not matter here as it's just screen coordinates

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b`.

It converts from any real number type (like `Int`, `Float` or `Double`) to any fractional type (like `Float`, `Double` or `Rational`).

Note that even though the general definition of this function (`fromRational . toRational`) does a slow conversion via the `Rational` type, [there are rewrite rules](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Float.html#line-1082) which use more efficient implementations for conversions between `Float` and `Double`.

Comment: That's the standard way. Should be noted though that the direct implementation is pretty inefficient, since it uses `Rational` as an intermediate. This could certainly be optimised away, but I'm not sure how reliable GHC does this – couldn't find an according `SPECIALIZE`ation in the code.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: [Found them](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Float.html#line-1082). They are implemented as rewrite rules, in this case to `GHC.Float.float2Double`, which is just a wrapper around the `float2Double#` primitive.

Comment: still wondering ..  why does hoogle not find this `realToFrac`?

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42: It does return it about 50 items down the list. It looks like it might not be taking instances into account when ranking the results, however, as it's giving similar rankings to e.g. `fromIntegral` even though there is no `Integral` instance for `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

[double2Float](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/GHC-Float.html#v:double2Float) :: Double -> Float